# Prevent creation of default collection in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I've read post [Making spring-data-mongodb multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325606/making-spring-data-mongodb-multi-tenant) and [Collection based multitenancy with Spring Data MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459810/collection-based-multitenancy-with-spring-data-mongodb). In the second post the issue is already mentioned: when the service starts it creates a "default" collection, which is not related to any real tenant, as the tenant is typically derived from the request context. Is there any way (despite deleting the default collection) to prevent the creation of the default collection?

Kind Regards,
Tibor