# Spring data mongo Multi tenant support

Tags: rest, multi-tenant, spring-data-mongodb

I have a requirement to enable multi tenant support for a spring boot application, it uses mongodb ,requirement is to use separate database based on tenant login.

Each request of REST service call will have the tenant information in header.Based on the tenant retrieved from service request, application should connect to corresponding database.

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325606/making-spring-data-mongodb-multi-tenant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making spring-data-mongodb multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325606/making-spring-data-mongodb-multi-tenant)