# Spring Boot WebFlux Reactive MongoDB: how to switch the database on each request?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux, multi-tenant

I'm working on a SaaS project using Spring WebFlux and Reactive MongoDB.
It needs to be a MultiTenant application and each tenant must use its own database.

As for now I just added the Reactive MongoDB dependency to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I extended the **AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration** in order to provide the **MongoClient** and the DatabaseName:

```
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {
    @Override
    public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
        System.out.println("ReactiveMongoClient");
        return MongoClients.create();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        System.out.println("DataBase name");
        return "gateway";
    }
}
```

The whole application is an OAuth 2.0 Resource Server and I'm able to retrieve the **TenantID** from the **Authentication** in the **ReactiveSecurityContextHolder**.

```
public Mono<String> tenantID() {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty())
            .flatMap((securityContext) -> {
                Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();

                if (authentication instanceof CustomAuthenticationToken) {
                    CustomAuthenticationToken customAuthenticationToken = (customAuthenticationToken) authentication;
                    Jwt jwt = customAuthenticationToken.getToken();

                    String issuer = jwt.getIssuer().toString();
                    return Mono.justOrEmpty(issuer);
                }

                return Mono.empty();
            });
}
```

What is the next step in order to switch the database based on the user (Authentication) performing the request?

**UPDATE:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800916/multi-tenancy-in-reactive-spring-boot-application-using-mongodb-reactive) is almost near to the goal, but almost one year ago [@mp911de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067527/mp911de)
said it was not possible.
Wondering if it is feasible now.
How could I implement a true reactive **ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory** that returns **Mono** so that I could access SecurityContext, hence the Authentication, before returning the **MongoDatabase**?

Comment: Are the different databases part of the same mongodb instance/cluster and use the same database users? Or do you need a complete new connection?

Comment: For a first release it would be ok to use the same mongodb instance, but I need to at least protect each database with the user credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a few months ago and wanted to share how I solved it.

### Solution 1: *do it yourself*

Spring does not provide any out-of-the-box solution for this problem. A few months ago i created a proof of concept how to solve it and just published the example project on Github.

[spring-mongodb-multi-tenancy-example](https://github.com/mgmeiner/spring-mongodb-multi-tenancy-example)

In short: I created a custom `MultiTenancyReactiveMongoTemplate` which internally delegates to the the actual `ReactiveMongoTemplate` based on the *tenantId* from *subscriberContext*. The *tenantId* is extracted from a http-request header in a custom WebFilter which puts it in the *subscriberContext*.

This workaround works for most cases and also supports auto-index creation and the use of the `ReactiveMongoRepository`'s.

But also has some limitations as Transactions, IndexOps on the `MultiTenancyReactiveMongoTemplate` or the `ReactiveGridFSTemplate` do not work with the provided solution. Some of the things could be implemented with other delegating 'templates' but some things will never work as these operations simply return scalar values (no `Publisher`) and there is no way to access the subscriberContext in these cases.

If you do not need these features you could probably go with this solution.

### Solution 2:

You spin up and configure instances of the service for each tenant/customer and put a reverse proxy 'before' these services. The reverse proxy decides which service should be used to handle the request. 
The reverse proxy can be implemented very easy with for example [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) which allows you to easily implement *predicates* which decide (e. g. based on a auth token) which service should be used.

With technologies like CloudFoundry or Kubernetes it is no that hard anymore to orchestrate the deployment of these tenant specific services and this solution makes it also easy to do tenant specific monitoring, alerting or even billing.

We chose solution **2** because overall this was easier and scales better for us.

Comment: Thanks. I was going for the 1st solution and got it working by accessing the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` in the `doGetDatabase` of the `MongoTemplate`.
It is also possible to specify which MongoTemplate to use for a set of repositories by putting on a `@Configuration` class (one for each MongoTemplate) this annotation

   `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = RepositoryLocation.TENANT, 
    reactiveMongoTemplateRef = DatabaseMode.TENANT)`

Comment: Yes, i had the same solution with overriding doGetDatabase on ReactiveMongoTemplate which also works very well but it requires you to configure a "default" MongoClient and thats what i wanted to avoid.

Comment: @gmeiner.m I am using the project that you gave us above as  base for a multitenancy, but I am try adding new Tenants. Could you please give a clue, how to add new tenants in the structure of your project?

Comment: @PaulDev In my example new tenants can be simply added  by updating the config. Take a look at the application.yml and MultiTenancyConfiguration class. MultiTenancyConfiguration configures the WebFilter + The MultiTenancyReactiveMongoTemplate. Hope this is the answer your looking for

Comment: @gmeiner.m Thanks a lot for you answer and your guidance. My idea is add "newtenant" dynamically, via one rest-endpoint ( if you want, you can check: https://github.com/PauloPortfolio/spring-webflux-mongo-multi-tenancy). Sort of simple multitenancy. I did it; however, the "only" way that your example is working is accepting the "tenants predefined in application.yml". My goal is add "new tenants" synamically via end-point. Can you give some tipo for that? Thanks a lot for your example and tips.

Comment: @PaulDev So this has nothing todo with the original question anymore. You can reach out me through my private email address you find at my github profile or via twitter.