# How to make Spring Data JPA and MongoDb multi-tenant at the same time?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb, multi-tenant

I am using Spring Data JPA and MongoDb in my rest application. My database structure is such that for each Customer type, we have a separate oracle and mongodb. Whenever a Customer makes an http request to my rest server, based on some request header parameter i determine the customer type.

For instance, for Customer type A, there will be an "Oracle database A" and "Mongo database A". Similarly there will be "Oracle database B" and "Mongo database B" for customer type B and so on. The number of Customer types are fixed.

Now what i want is, suppose if Customer B makes an http request, then for this particular thread, all oracle hits should go to Oracle Database B and all mongo hits should go to Mongo database B.

I am aware of *AbstractRoutingDataSource* for making JPA multi-tenant but cannot think of a way to make both MongoDb and Oracle multi-tenant at the same time.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are using spring-data-mongodb for mongodb access, right? It's a bit fuzzy in the question so I thought to ask and clarify for SO users who are trying to help for this question.

Comment: Yes, i am using spring data mongodb for mongodb acess.

Comment: Does [Making spring-data-mongodb multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24205593/2641683) and [multi-tenant-spring-mongodb](https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb) help?

Comment: I also found [Guide to multi-tenancy with Spring Boot and MongoDB](https://medium.com/@alexantaniuk/guide-to-multi-tenancy-with-spring-boot-and-mongodb-78ea5ef89466) doing precisely same thing. You will have to combine JPA and mongodb connection switching logic at same execution point the way I see with these solutions.