# how to implement multi-tenant using spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am new to multi-tenancy with mongodb using spring-data-mongodb, we need to use spring-data-mongodb for rest APIs and scheduling tasks( we have more than one schedulers in our application) in the same code with thread-safe. Is autowiring mongoTemplate will make application thread safe as the same mongoTemplate will be accessed from Schedulers and APIs both. Please get me the good practice in such a situation.

Regards

Kris

Answer (score 1):

MongoTemplate itself is thread-safe, i.e. you can call it from multiple threads at the same time, and it will work correctly, i.e. send the different requests correctly to MongoDB.

But that doesn't guarantee consistency: if the scheduler is running and executes multiple updates in the same task, an API call can possibly get some updated records and some other records that aren't updated yet.

By the way: multi-tenancy is having data from multiple organisational entities in the same database. I'm not sure how that links to your question, did you mean multi-threading?

Comment: thanks for your answer, we are having one tenantdb / customer in same server , and is multi-tenancy, can I have a situation like this: does scheduler set a tenant name will have impact on tenant name coming from API(s), or scheduler thread and API thread are INDEPENDENT with their tenant codes, please clarify. Kris

Comment: If you have multiple tenants, how do you store them? Different databases? And a single application?

Comment: We are storing as different databases and a single application, please clarify

Comment: See new answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If you use different databases, then you can't use an autowired MongoTemplate.
For autowiring, there must be a single instance, but since the database connection string is a dependency of a MongoTemplate, there must be a single database as well.

You could go for an approach where you do not auto-wire the MongoTemplate directly, but use some sort of factory pattern to create the correct MongoTemplate for the current tenant. See [Making spring-data-mongodb multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325606/making-spring-data-mongodb-multi-tenant) for some examples. (It's an old question, but its answers get updated every now and then).

Or you could go with an infrastructural solution, and deploy separate instances of your application, one for each tenant, e.g. on Kubernetes.