# Spring-Data: specify which MongoTemplate a MongoRepository should use

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

The following configuration is given:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

  @Bean
  Mongo mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
    return new Mongo("localhost");
  }

  @Bean(name = "MovieTemplate")
  MongoTemplate beagleTemplate(Mongo mongo) {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo, "MovieDatabase");
  }

  @Bean(name = "AnotherTemplate")
  MongoTemplate tmdbTemplate(Mongo mongo) {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo, "AnotherDatabase");
  }
}
```

I need a repository to access movies, which looks kinda like this:

```
@Repository
public interface MoviesRepository extends
    MongoRepository<ProductPages, String> {

    ... some method declarations to access movies ...
}
```

Is there an annotation driven way to tell the repository which template to use?
If not, what else could be done to solve the problem?

Comment: Not sure about Repository, Look at annotations Qualifier and Autowire. Can auto wire desired template with Qualifier. I am not sure though.

Comment: tried it with qualifiers and autowired, had no luck, guess its not meant to work that way. Well the qualifier annotation is not applicable to classes anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use this annotation on the Configuration class

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(
basePackages = {"com.yyy.dao.jpa", "com.xxx.dao.jpa"},
mongoTemplateRef = "MovieTemplate"
)
```

and configure this:

1. enumerate all the packages/classes to scan to find mongo dao that will be included on this configuration
2. specify the MongoTemplate(bean name) that will be used by the Mongo Dao scanned by this configuration

So you need a configuration class for every set of Mongo Dao along with their corresponding MongoTemplate.

NOTE: If you intend to use a different Mongo client for each template, then you have to make sure the appropriate Mongo client bean is passed to the MongoTemplate, such as using a Qualifier, or a different argument name that matches the Mongo's method name with declared @Bean.

Comment: thank you for your effort to suggest a solution vine, looks promising! Unfortunately I don't have the time to verify it in order to accept it, maybe someone (the more ppl. the better) else will do so. Have an upvote for your effort.

Comment: btw on which version of spring-data-mongodb have you tested your solution? Is it a new feature which was not present in 1.3.1?

Comment: I am using 1.7.2, but this is supported since 1.3.1, check this out
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/EnableMongoRepositories.html

BTW this is a basic configuration for multiple mongoTemplate and MongoClient, similar to multiple JPA Datasources.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this question: [Spring-data-mongodb connect to multiple databases in one Mongo instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078669/spring-data-mongodb-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-one-mongo-instance)

Besides solving this issue annotation-driven spring-data-mongodb(1.3.1.RELEASE ) doesn't seem to offer an out-of-the-box solution at all :/