# Multi-tenant mongodb database based with spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to make my web application that is using mongodb and spring-data multitenat.

Basically I would like to replicate all my entities(collections) into different databases. Then (based on some rule as for example the user that is logged in the system) I want to store some entity instance (document) into the right database.

For example I have a Service Called DBNameProviderService.getDbName() that dynamically returns me the name of the database. How can I use this service to dynamically select the correct Db?

**Edited**

Sorry if it is not enough clear. Maybe with an example will be more clear.

In my system I can registe/login users (they are stored stored in the User collection in database named general_db).

I have also an entity A (marked as multitenant simply extending an interface). If I am logged in as User1 I want to store an A instance always in the Database User1_db in the collection A, while if I am logged in as User2 and I want to store an A instance in User2_db in the collection A.

So in this scenario the problem is that I cannot create a mongotemplate bean for each user because users can register in the system, so it is dynamic. I need that the MongoTemplate choose dynamically the database.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is and what you need help with. Your function would return the correct database based on input values.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I updated the question, please have a look if now the problem is more clear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at my github project, I had a very similar problem.

https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

See same kind of issues [Spring-data-mongodb connect to multiple databases in one Mongo instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078669/spring-data-mongodb-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-one-mongo-instance?rq=1)
There is also the possibility of sharding and set as part of the key the id you want to use and search.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced similar problem while using spring mongodb as multitenant. Finally i figured out a way by using Adapter to manage the MongoTemplates in a static Collection.

SpringMongoConfigAdapater is a sample snippet which can help the overview.

Spring Config:

```
<bean id="springConfig"  class="com.company.config.SpringMongoConfigAdapater"  >

<!-- default db initialization -->

    <property name="defaultDBName" value="${MONGOHQ_DB:db}"></property> 

<!-- mongo instance is referred to http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd  -->

     <property name="mongo" ref="mongo"></property>

        </bean>
```

SpringMongoConfigAdapter:

```
public class SpringMongoConfigAdapater {
   // Each Tenant is referenced to MongoTemplate
 static HashMap<String, MongoTemplate> templateMap = new HashMap<>();
 // Each Tenant is referenced to GridFS Template
    static  HashMap<String, GridFsTemplate> gridfsMap = new HashMap<>();
    // @Autowired
    Mongo mongo;
    @Autowired
    private MongoConverter mappingMongoConverter;
    public HashMap<String, MongoTemplate> getTemplateMap() {
        return templateMap;
    }
    /**
     * @return the defaultDBName
     */
    public String getDefaultDBName() {
        return defaultDBName;
    }   /**
     * @param defaultDBName the defaultDBName to set
     */
    public void setDefaultDBName(String defaultDBName) {
        this.defaultDBName = defaultDBName;
    }
    String defaultDBName;
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public MongoTemplate templateManager() throws Exception {
        String dbName = MyThreadLocal.getDBName();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(dbName)) {
            dbName = defaultDBName;
        }
        if (templateMap.get(dbName) == null) {
            MongoTemplate template = mongoTemplate(dbName);
            templateMap.put(dbName, template);
        }
        return templateMap.get(dbName);
    }
    //this is for gridfs template.
    public GridFsTemplate gridfsTemplateManager() throws Exception {
        String dbName = MyThreadLocal.getDBName();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(dbName)) {
            dbName = defaultDBName;
        }
        if (gridfsMap.get(dbName) == null) {
            GridFsTemplate template = new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(dbName), mappingMongoConverter);
            gridfsMap.put(dbName, template);
        }
        return gridfsMap.get(dbName);
    }
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(String name) throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(name));
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory(String name) throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, name);
    }
    /**
     * @return the gridfsMap
     */
    public HashMap<String, GridFsTemplate> getGridfsMap() {
        return gridfsMap;
    }
    /**
     * @param gridfsMap the gridfsMap to set
     */
    public void setGridfsMap(HashMap<String, GridFsTemplate> gridfsMap) {
        this.gridfsMap = gridfsMap;
    }
}
```

Now while calling from your code,

```
 springMongoConfigAdapater .templateManager().getMongoOps().findAll(User.class);
```

On top of it, Use ThreadLocal to initialize the MultiTenant Identifier (which could be dbName)
I gave a detailed info which might help you, 
Click [here](http://cloudtipsandissues.blogspot.in/2015/01/mongo-multitenancy-with-spring-java.html)!

Comment: How would you deal custom authentication for each database with this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this for springboot 2.3.3

https://github.com/jose-m-thomas/mongo_multi_tenancy_spring_boot_2_3_3

overriding doGetMongoDatabase helped to achieve multi tenancy

```
    protected MongoDatabase doGetMongoDatabase(String dbName) {   
    }
```