# spring data mongodb connect to multiple database instance for each tenant

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I have a web application which uses Spring and connects to mongdb using spring data mongodb.
I want to extend it by connecting to multiple database instance for each tenant. There are some solutions which are available on stackoverflow. One was mentioned on [Multi-tenant mongodb database based with spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791656/multi-tenant-mongodb-database-based-with-spring-data) where the code was on github on the following link-
https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb

I have a question regarding this? Will this approach work for concurrent requests?
I am also doing the same thing, autowiring the MongoTemplate and Repository.
Since these beans are singletons, they will be the same for each request. Then how will the database change for different request and what happens when multiple requests are being served in parallel?