# Java Spring Data MongoDB Change Database During Runtime(Multi-tenancy)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, multi-tenant

I want to have the same structure of collections in multiple databases as follows

```
Database A:
 CollectionA
 CollectionB

Database B:
 CollectionA
 CollectionB
```

Lets say i create my documents with the respective repositories
Eg.

```
@Document(collection = collectionA)
@Document(collection = collectionB)
```

How can i make a configuration to force spring to swap databases for the repository beans between opperations ? I have searched and i have found that i need to create a mongoTemplate bean it dosent seem to work , This method is called only once when the repositories are autowired but not where an insert is made.

Eg.

```
# Inside a service
@Autowired
DocumentARepository documentARepository;

documentARepository.insert(documentA); # Inserts in Database A Collection A
TenantContext.setTenant("Database B"); # Changes MongoDb Repository Tenant (Database) thread safe class i use for jdbc multitenancy
docucmentARepository.insert(documentB); #Insert in Database B Collection A
```

Have looked at [Multi-tenant mongodb database based with spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791656/multi-tenant-mongodb-database-based-with-spring-data) and its an old version of spring data mongodb im using 3.1.3

If anyone can suggest how i can debug what beans are used during the insertion of a document it would be welcome to figure it out on my own.Have no idea how i would go with this to manually figure it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: to write to two different targets you need to implement two distinct clients in your code.  SpringDataMongo assumes you will only ever need one client and does not provide this option out of the box.  That is not to say, you couldn't create multiple clients if you want.  You may be better suited implementing change streams as a means of keeping two targets in sync with each other.  Or perhaps use the MongoDB replication, or use the new MongoDB Cluster2Cluster sync option https://www.mongodb.com/docs/cluster-to-cluster-sync/current/

Comment: Might have not explained it well but i only have one cluster im speaking about the databases on the mongo server.

Each database will have the same collections but different data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will solve this by ditching MongoRepositorie interfaces all together and use a MongoTemplate bean instead. Configured like so :

Mongo Configuration File

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultiTenantMongoDbFactory multiTenantMongoDatabaseFactory(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        return new MultiTenantMongoDbFactory(mongoClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MultiTenantMongoDbFactory multiTenantMongoDatabaseFactory) {
        return new MongoTemplate(multiTenantMongoDatabaseFactory);
    }
}
```

MultiTenantMongoDbFactory File (This is used a the factory that create the mongo templates seems to be used to determine the database for each save although i have not tested for backround batching)

```
public class MultiTenantMongoDbFactory implements MongoDatabaseFactory {

    private final MongoClient mongoClient;
    private final PersistenceExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

    public MultiTenantMongoDbFactory(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
        this.exceptionTranslator = new MongoExceptionTranslator();
    }

    public MultiTenantMongoDbFactory(MongoClient mongoClient, ClientSession session) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
        this.exceptionTranslator = new MongoExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Override
    public MongoDatabase getMongoDatabase() throws DataAccessException {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
    }

    @Override
    public MongoDatabase getMongoDatabase(String dbName) throws DataAccessException {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);
    }

    @Override
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslator getExceptionTranslator() {
        return exceptionTranslator;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientSession getSession(ClientSessionOptions options) {
        return mongoClient.startSession(options);
    }

    @Override
    public MongoDatabaseFactory withSession(ClientSession session) {
        // Create a new MultiTenantMongoDbFactory instance with the same MongoClient and the provided ClientSession.
        return new MultiTenantMongoDbFactory.ClientSessionBoundMongoDbFactory(session, this);
    }

    static final private class ClientSessionBoundMongoDbFactory implements MongoDatabaseFactory {

        private final ClientSession session;
        private final MongoDatabaseFactory delegate;

        public ClientSessionBoundMongoDbFactory(ClientSession session, MongoDatabaseFactory delegate) {
            this.session = session;
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory#getMongoDatabase()
         */
        @Override
        public MongoDatabase getMongoDatabase() throws DataAccessException {
            return proxyMongoDatabase(delegate.getMongoDatabase());
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory#getMongoDatabase(java.lang.String)
         */
        @Override
        public MongoDatabase getMongoDatabase(String dbName) throws DataAccessException {
            return proxyMongoDatabase(delegate.getMongoDatabase(dbName));
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory#getExceptionTranslator()
         */
        @Override
        public PersistenceExceptionTranslator getExceptionTranslator() {
            return delegate.getExceptionTranslator();
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory#getSession(com.mongodb.ClientSessionOptions)
         */
        @Override
        public ClientSession getSession(ClientSessionOptions options) {
            return delegate.getSession(options);
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory#withSession(com.mongodb.session.ClientSession)
         */
        @Override
        public MongoDatabaseFactory withSession(ClientSession session) {
            return delegate.withSession(session);
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory#isTransactionActive()
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isTransactionActive() {
            return session != null && session.hasActiveTransaction();
        }

        private MongoDatabase proxyMongoDatabase(MongoDatabase database) {
            return createProxyInstance(session, database, MongoDatabase.class);
        }

        private MongoDatabase proxyDatabase(com.mongodb.session.ClientSession session, MongoDatabase database) {
            return createProxyInstance(session, database, MongoDatabase.class);
        }

        private MongoCollection<?> proxyCollection(com.mongodb.session.ClientSession session,
                                                   MongoCollection<?> collection) {
            return createProxyInstance(session, collection, MongoCollection.class);
        }

        private <T> T createProxyInstance(com.mongodb.session.ClientSession session, T target, Class<T> targetType) {

            ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
            factory.setTarget(target);
            factory.setInterfaces(targetType);
            factory.setOpaque(true);

            factory.addAdvice(new SessionAwareMethodInterceptor<>(session, target, ClientSession.class, MongoDatabase.class,
                    this::proxyDatabase, MongoCollection.class, this::proxyCollection));

            return targetType.cast(factory.getProxy(target.getClass().getClassLoader()));
        }

        public ClientSession getSession() {
            return this.session;
        }

        public MongoDatabaseFactory getDelegate() {
            return this.delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(@Nullable Object o) {
            if (this == o)
                return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
                return false;

            MultiTenantMongoDbFactory.ClientSessionBoundMongoDbFactory that = (MultiTenantMongoDbFactory.ClientSessionBoundMongoDbFactory) o;

            if (!ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(this.session, that.session)) {
                return false;
            }
            return ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(this.delegate, that.delegate);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(this.session);
            result = 31 * result + ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(this.delegate);
            return result;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "MongoDatabaseFactorySupport.ClientSessionBoundMongoDbFactory(session=" + this.getSession() + ", delegate="
                    + this.getDelegate() + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

TenantContext file what i use to set the tenant context for both jdbc mariadb and mongodb cause i have both

```
public class TenantContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static String getCurrentTenant() {
        if (currentTenant.get() == null){
            currentTenant.set("DEV_TEST");
        }
        return currentTenant.get();
    }

    public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) {
        currentTenant.set(tenant);
    }

    public static void clear() {
        currentTenant.remove();
    }
}
```

Added the full code here if someone wants to copy

https://github.com/mplein2/spring_data_mongodb_mutlitenancy

Edit : After making the changes the repositories that are generated are multi tenant also . No need to use the mongo template directly