# multiple Mongo database and spring-data

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I am in the process of finding out how do I dynamically connect to different mongo db's based on the user that logs in. I see multiple posts that talks about it but since I am new to this just wanted to understand more on how to implement it. In our application while creating the user account we could create different db files based on the userName, which acts as a key.
So we know which database to connect so it is just matter of selecting correct Factory I guess. 
I see following constructor in the template code.

```
public MongoTemplate(Mongo mongo, String databaseName) {
    this(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, databaseName), null);
}
```

My  current Spring java config does following

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    UserCredentials userCredentials = 
            new UserCredentials(
                    env.getRequiredProperty(databasePropertyNames.getDBUsernamePropertyName()), 
                    env.getRequiredProperty(databasePropertyNames.getDBPasswordPropertyName()));

    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo().getObject(),
            env.getRequiredProperty(databasePropertyNames.getDBNamePropertyName()), 
            userCredentials);
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
    mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);

    return mongoTemplate;
}


Questions:-
1.Will there be multiple SimpleMongoDbFactory objects that I need to create based on the user that logged in?
If yes then how do I do it and do I need to maintain that object Map?
2. How would I do set those in mongoTemplate at runtime?
```

Your help would be highly appreciated:)

Comment: Following posts worked well for me [https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb][
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078669/spring-data-mongodb-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-one-mongo-instance?rq=1] Along with this one has to update the Mongo instance to allow the user from default database to be able to write in any other database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following posts worked well for me

github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb

[Spring-data-mongodb connect to multiple databases in one Mongo instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078669/spring-data-mongodb-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-one-mongo-instance?rq=1)

Along with this one has to update the Mongo instance to allow the user from default database to be able to write in to any other database