# Switching between databases Spring MongoDb

Tags: java, spring, spring-mongo

I have a case, where I need to switch between the mongo databases using Spring mongodata (Version: 1.6.2). Currently, I have default database configured in db-config.xml with  mongo template, and have annotated repositories; Need is to switch from one db/template to another at runtime; do necessary actions and switch back to default one.
I referred to couple of links, 
[Spring-data-mongodb connect to multiple databases in one Mongo instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078669/spring-data-mongodb-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-one-mongo-instance)
and 
[Making spring-data-mongodb multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325606/making-spring-data-mongodb-multi-tenant)
I need to use same set of repositories at runtime. Is it possible to handle my case at configuration level? or do we need to extend Dbfactory to achieve this?
with Dbfactory, can I use same set of annotated repositories?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend:

```
   1.  `SimpleMongoDbFactory`: returning custom DB in DB `getDb(String dbName)`.

    2. `MongoTemplate`: Supplying above factory.
```

Use appropriate `MongoTemplate` with the help of `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Amdalal, Can you please give us more information how to use the different mongo template for the same repository.

Comment: check this https://gist.github.com/amdalal/bc5e573762cc45a6da14a3fbc723d8c0

Answer (score 1):

I once had a very similar problem.
I published the code on github, check it out [multi-tenant-spring-mongodb](https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb)

You basically have to extend `SimpleMongoDbFactory` and handle other hosts too. I just did handle multiple databases on the same server. That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per your code, I understand, we can set mongo template only once. I tried connecting to different dbs on same server, this is working fine. But, In my case, databases are in different server boxes. Is it possible to connect to a db on different server, dynamically?

Comment: is this resolved? I was unable to update the database during runtime.
context.getBean(SimpleMongoDbFactory.class).getDb("Test");

But it was not working, Thanks in advance.

Comment: @devanathan could you open a github issue instead? stackoverlflow isn't a bug tracker ;)