# Configure Multiple MongoDB repositories with Spring Data Mongo

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have 2 Mongodb databases connected to a Spring Boot app with 2 MongoTemplate-s:

**mongoTemplate** (the default bean name,  connects to default db)

**mongoAppTemplate** (connects to another database on run-time)

I have a lot of MongoRepository-s that use mongoTemplate but I also want to create some that would use mongoAppTemplate.

***How can I configure 2 MongoRepository-s to use different MongoTemplate -s with Java configuration ?***

I found a way to do it with XML (link below), but I really want to keep it all annotation based

[Spring-data-mongodb connect to multiple databases in one Mongo instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078669/spring-data-mongodb-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-one-mongo-instance?rq=1)

Comment: By "keep it all annotation based", are you just talking about Java-config for the connections?  Or is the issue about how to use the different connections in the same or different classes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The base idea is to separate the package hierarchy that contains your repositories into two different paths:

- *com.whatever.repositories.main* package for the main db repository interfaces
- *com.whatever.repositories.secondary* package for the other db repository interfaces

Your XML configuration should be something such as:

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.whatever.repositories.main" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate"/>
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.whatever.repositories.secondary" mongo-template-ref="mongoAppTemplate"/>
```

**EDIT**

[@EnableMongoRepositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/EnableMongoRepositories.html) annotation is not `@Repeatable`, but you can have two `@Configuration` classes, each annotated with `@EnableMongoRepositories` in order to achieve the same using annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.whatever.repositories.main", mongoTemplateRef = "mongoTemplate")
public class MainMongoConfig {
    ....
}

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.whatever.repositories.secondary", mongoTemplateRef = "mongoAppTemplate")
public class SecondaryMongoConfig {
    ....
}
```

And a third `@Configuration` annotated class which `@Import` the other two.

Comment: Can the same result be achieved through annotations?

Comment: @orid Wondering if this approach is taken, adding a third `@Configuration` annotated class is redundant? Otherwise skipping the `@Configuration` annotation in the first two classes and then consolidating into a third class

Comment: How to dynamically configure it? I mean, I have a list of templates, and want to use one of them based on certain conditions.

Comment: Then at last, how to inject a MongoRepository instance to my service? would you please compete the whole sample? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @OriDar, Is there any way to switch between the two mongo database in the same instance via repository pattern?

Comment: Super important note here:  The `MongoRepository` interfaces MUST be in different packages.  I also didn't need a 3rd class.