# Spring Data Mongo - Dynamically change repository template

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have this scenario: same database structure (same collections) replicated in multiple mongo databases. This mean that I have one mongo repository for each collection (Document).

Now I need to manage these databases through the same Control Panel App, connecting to each one of them dynamically, and using the same repository classes (the databases are identical).

I know that I can specify known templates for repositories as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681546/configure-multiple-mongodb-repositories-with-spring-data-mongo), but this implies that I have to know the database's connection properties at startup. How can I implement a dynamic behaviour of that, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core interface you might want to look at is `MongoDBFactory`. You can provide a custom one by overriding `mongoDbFactory()` in `AbstractMongoConfiguration` or just an ordinary bean definition in XML.

To transparently switch between different databases, simply keep track of the one selected in the implementation and return a `DB` instance according to that.

Comment: Is it possible to change not just database but the repository too? I mean a different monogdb host. Can I create a new monogTemplate and map it to the repository interfaces during runtime?