# How to specify the using mongo database in a MongoRepository when there are multiple databases

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In my spring boot application i have configured two databases in my yml file. So now I want to specify which database is to use in each MongoRepository. Is this possible? If so, how to do it? Thanks in advance.

yml file :

```
spring:
  data:
mongodb:
first:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017
  database: db_admin
      rest:
        base-path: /admin

second:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27018
  database: `user_forms`
      rest:
        base-path: /users
```

So in User MongoRepository i want to use the `user_forms` database.

The user MongoRepository :

```
  @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users",path = "users")
  public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

  List<User> findByUserId(String id);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure Multiple MongoDB repositories with Spring Data Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681546/configure-multiple-mongodb-repositories-with-spring-data-mongo)

Comment: its using the mongoTemplate approach, i have used the MongoRepository. so its not a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot auto configuration provides a default MongoTemplate to facilitate generating MongoDB Repositories.

Nevertheless if you want to use multi MongoDB databases, you would need to

1. register MongoTemplates for every MongoDB databases
2. designate each of the MongoTemplates to base packages of MongoRepositories accordingly, so that Spring Data MongoDB is informed to use the right template when generating repositories.

For example, say you registered 2 MongoTemplates, namely templateAdmin and templateUser, configured explicitly to their MongoDB. Then you could use code like this to inform Spring Data MongoDB which repositories use which template:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(
  basePackages = "com.the.base.package.name.of.admin.repositories",
  mongoTemplateRef = "adminTemplateBeanName")
@Configuration
public class AdminMongoConfig {

  @Bean
  public MongoTemplate adminTemplateBeanName() {
    //...
  }
}
```

[Configure Multiple MongoDB repositories with Spring Data Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681546/configure-multiple-mongodb-repositories-with-spring-data-mongo) Basically explained almost all points what I have said. So my wild guess is that you may have a misconception that MongoTemplate is irrelevant to MongoRepository, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer despite having marked the question as a duplicate, as there is some confusion whether `MongoRepository` uses `MongoTemplate`.

When you inject your MongoRepository, it is proxied by an instance of `SimpleMongoRepository` class. it has a field

```
private final MongoOperations mongoOperations;
```

`MongoOperations` is an interface, and `MongoTemplate` is its implementation.

Now, the question is where does this default mongo template come from in a Spring Boot application.
Look at `MongoDataAutoConfiguration`

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory,
                                   MongoConverter converter) {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
}
```

Therefore, I am still claiming it is a duplicate of: [Configure Multiple MongoDB repositories with Spring Data Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681546/configure-multiple-mongodb-repositories-with-spring-data-mongo)