# How to change one param on bean created with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got two repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface SpringLRepository extends MongoRepository<L, String> {
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface SpringSRepository extends MongoRepository<S, String> {
}
```

In `properties` file i've got:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=example
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=l
```

Now i want to have seperate properties for `SpringLRepository` and `SpringSRepository` or only change part of them like `spring.data.mongodb.database` parameter. 
Can I achieve it keeping `@Repository` annotation?

Comment: See [Configure Multiple MongoDB repositories with Spring Data Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31681546/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, tried to add it, but this is vague for me so I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166933/two-mongo-repositories-with-different-properties